# What does "Focusable Elements Should Have Interactive Semantics" mean in a figure?

Tags: html, firefox, accessibility, figure

I am reviewing a site with the Firefox accessibility inspector, and there is one problem that I cannot solve.  The following piece of html yields the error, "Focusable Elements Should Have Interactive Semantics", and I cannot figure out why.  This is one of a list of captioned thumbnails that link to different pages.

```
<figure class="col-sm-4" aria-label="{{ label }}" title="{{ title }}">
    <a href="{% url 'example' %}" role="img" aria-label="{{ label }}" title="{{ title }}" tabindex="0">
        <img src="{{ src }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ alt }}" title="{{ title }}" loading="lazy" />
    </a>
    <figcaption class="text-center bottom-20">
        <strong>{{ text }}</strong><br/>
        {{ text2 }}
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Any ideas?  I explicitly added tabindex="0" to the a tag just in case that solved it, but still has this error message regardless of whether or not that is there.  I also tried adding tabindex="-1" to the figure, figcaption, and img tags to make them all non-focusable in case that was the problem, but that did not do anything either.  From what I can tell, the "a" link is the only focusable element, and the "a" tag is considered interactive semantics, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Where do you see the error you reference? Are you using a validator of some kind?

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I was using the Firefox accessibility inspector.  It's the Accessibility tab of the Firefox Inspector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is the misuse of `role="img"`.

What you are essentially saying is that the anchor is an image.

So the browser sees this as an image as far as screen readers and the accessibility tree are concerned, but still present the item as focusable as it is a link.

This results in a mismatch of expectations, think of it in reverse, it is essentially the same as making an image focusable, but there is no reason to do this as an image in of itself is not interactive.

If you remove this `role` from the hyperlink (as it is not correct) you should find that the problem goes away as now the hyperlink is seen as a hyperlink by the accessibility tree.

An additional point here is that you have an `aria-label` on the `figure` and hyperlink. This will override the contents of the hyperlink so the image should be made decorative (using `alt=""` and `role="presentation"`) and you should remove the `aria-label` from the `figure` as well.

Alternatively remove the `aria-label` from the image and `figure` and instead use the `alt` attribute on the image as the link text. That is down to judgement as I cannot see what values you have for each but I would say the `alt` attribute should be the hyperlink content as this is more robust than `aria`.

Finally having the `title` attribute on both the link and the image is unnecessary, I would just put it on the image.

### proposed code

As discussed I cannot see your `aria-label` or `alt` content so I can't tell which is most appropriate, but the below is how I would structure your HTML from the info I can see.

```
<figure class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="{% url 'example' %}">
        <img src="{{ src }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ alt }}" title="{{ title }}" loading="lazy" />
    </a>
    <figcaption class="text-center bottom-20">
        <strong>{{ text }}</strong><br/>
        {{ text2 }}
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

### Quick fiddle to show behaviour

```html
<h2>incorrect, no link text read out</h2>
<figure class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="https://google.com" role="img">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="link text" title="not really needed but should be link text if used" loading="lazy" />
    </a>
    <figcaption class="text-center bottom-20">
         <strong>supporting info</strong><br/>
        for image
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<h2>link text is read out</h2>
<figure class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="link text" title="not really needed but should be link text if used" loading="lazy" />
    </a>
    <figcaption class="text-center bottom-20">
        <strong>supporting info</strong><br/>
        for image
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong with the snippet.

---

**Firstly, fixing the initial error.**

By default, an `a` element will be in the focus order and the user can tab to it, by adding the inappropriate role `role=img` it is now removed from that.

> When an inappropriate role like paragraph is used for an interactive element, the element will not receive focus, and the screen reader will not announce anything.
> – https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.0/focus-order-semantics

Removing the `role=img` and `tabindex` from the hyperlink and ensuring the `img` has suitable `alt` text will act as the readble text from the screen-reader.

Comment: interestingly the advice from Deque is not quite right (at least in NVDA), the element **will receive focus** but nothing will be announced if a non-interactive `role` is used. I had to check as Deque don't normally get it wrong. That makes sense in response to the error of "Focusable Elements Should Have Interactive Semantics" as it still believes the hyperlink is focusable even if it is an image as far as the accessibility tree is concerned. I added a fiddle to my answer to see if you get the same result as that is quite an interesting point(assuming you have a screen reader handy :-P)